# Not possible to update value of encrypted column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I have used Always Encrypted to encrypt values in a column. My connection string looks like this (everything is working fine and the client is able to decrypt the values):

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=10.10.10.1\INST2;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=yes;ColumnEncryption=Enabled;
```

Then I try to update one of the encrypted values using the following code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_SecurityUsers_GetDetails 
(
    @Firstname NVARCHAR(128)
)
AS
BEGIN;

UPDATE SecurityUsers
SET FirstName = @Firstname
WHERE login = 'system.export.service'

SELECT Login, FirstName, LastName
FROM SecurityUsers

END;
```

the SP is called like this:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.NamedParameters = True
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[usp_SecurityUsers_GetDetails]"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Firstname", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 128, "system_text")
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    Set recordSet = cmd.Execute
```

But I get the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Encryption
>   scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@P1'. The encryption scheme for
>   the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'PLAINTEXT') and the
>   expression near line '1' expects it to be (encryption_type =
>   'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'CEK_SecurityLevelNormal', column_encryption_key_database_name =
>   'test') (or weaker).

It's very strange, because I am able to update the field if the code is not encapsulated in stored procedure and directly executed in the SQL Server Management Studio.

Also, calling the `SP` directly in the SSMS works.

EDIT:

Updating to `.net 4.6.3` does not change anything. What I am seeing is, if I change the connection string `ColumnEncryption=Enabled;` to `Column Encryption Setting=Enabled;`, I am getting different error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type
>   clash: ntext is incompatible with nvarchar(128) encrypted with
>   (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'CEK_SecurityLevelNormal', column_encryption_key_database_name =
>   'test')

Comment: Working with ADO.Net, you have to be using .NET Framework 4.6 or later to fully support always encrypted. I'd think there are low odds that similar engineering effort has been expended on (non-.NET) ADO. You may have to create .NET code that's exposed to your calling code as COM wrappers (and can then use the `ForceColumnEncryption` property if it's not picked up transparently)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the support is [baked into the ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver); if ADO uses the standard APIs for adding parameters, it *ought* to work. At the same time, however, it's probably going to be hard to get anyone at MS to sign off on that if it doesn't...

Comment: Yes, but e.g. `ForceColumnEncryption` is surfaced as a property for ADO.NET parameters. No such equivalent that I can see for [ADO Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameter-object-properties-methods-and-events)

Comment: I believe you are both partially correct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider Assuming your application has the required database permissions and can access the column master key, the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server will encrypt any query parameters that target encrypted columns, and will decrypt data retrieved from encrypted columns returning plaintext values of .NET types, corresponding to the SQL Server data types set for the columns in the database schema.

Comment: If Always Encrypted is not enabled, queries with parameters that target encrypted columns will fail. Queries can still retrieve data from encrypted columns, as long as the query has no parameters targeting encrypted columns. However, the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server will not attempt to decrypt any values retrieved from encrypted columns and the application will receive binary encrypted data (as byte arrays).

Comment: @JacobH - `CreateObject("ADODB.Command")` - we're doing ADO, not ADO.Net, so anything that the .NET Framework provider might do is moot.

Comment: @JacobH I can see the encrypted values in the application, but I am not able to edit them. I guess the driver is not able to handle my request correctly, because of the legacy tech I am using.

Comment: @JacobH: The .NET provider is irrelevant here; the code is using (classic) ADO, meaning the OLEDB provider using the ODBC driver. (That may point at another failure point: the OLEDB provider for ODBC may not tickle the ODBC layer in the right way, despite the connection string.)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good point, I missed that it wasn't ADO.net

Comment: Wild shot in the dark: try setting `Command.Prepared = True`. This should have no real effect on how the parameters get passed, but it might.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, unfortunately the same result.

Comment: @JeroenMostert In the link you have provided it is said I need .net 4.6 and I 've just check with the sys administrator is 4.0. We are going to update and I will test again.

Comment: That should have no effect whatsoever because you're not using .NET (it would be better if you did, as you'd get better support :-)) You're using classic ADO, with its own OLEDB driver to access the ODBC driver. Updating any of ODBC and MSDASQL may have effect, but updating .NET shouldn't. (Not that it can *hurt* -- it might install some updated dependencies, even.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am using the lasted ODBC Driver (13.1). What do you mean by updating the MSDASQL driver? Also, why do you think I am using OLEDDB driver to access the ODBC driver?

Comment: You're using OLE DB because that's all ADO "speaks"; it's a COM-based technology and OLE DB is essentially the COM wrapper around the drivers. That `Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}` selects the OLE DB interface of the ODBC driver. MSDASQL is the name of the OLE DB for ODBC provider; [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-odbc) for more. Forget what I said about updating, though; it's been deprecated for a while now and I can't find anything more recent than 2008 (and it's apparently part of the OS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was feeling that the issue must be in the way I am trying to modify the data as I am able to read it. And it was so lame.

In my stored procedure I have `nvarchar(256)`. In the ASP I am using `adLongVarChar` instead `adVarWChar`. The error seems more reasonable now:

> Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@P1'.

---

The conclusion is one is able to read encrypted data and modify it using ADO and ODBC driver.